# Autorizacion, rol Identity Net Core 6

Tags: net, identity, core

Soy nuevo utilizando el identity de net core.
Necesito asignar permisos a paginas a los usuarios, que estas asignaciones se realicen en forma dinámica, sin necesidad de tocar código cada vez que se crea un rol o grupo.
ejemplo:
Un grupo Administrador tiene acceso a las paginas:

1. CreaUsuario
2. Productos
3. Bodegas

Asi Tambien Un grupo de Contabilidad tiene acceso a las paginas

1. Productos
2. Bodegas
3. Caja

esto es sin estar agregando en [Authorize(Roles = Administrador + "," + Contabilidad )], que esto sea dinámico por cada rol o grupo que yo cree le asigne los permisos a las paginas que necesite.
Debo agregar alguna tabla extra a la base de datos de identity?

Me pueden ayudar por favor!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.